# Google Font letters scramble up sometimes on refresh only in localhost

Tags: html, css, fonts, webfonts, google-font-api

We have a strange problem with Google Fonts while developing via localhost. On random refresh the letters of text scramble up. This happens about once every 5 refreshes. The images below show the letters scrambled up and the way they're supposed to be shown.

[image: Letters scrambled up]

[image: Correct way]

Also, while the letters are scrambled up, when we open the inspector and deselect the font-family property and then select it again, the letters show the correct way.

We don't encounter this problem when we deploy to a live server. Did anyone else have this problem?

I only did encounter this problem in Google Chrome, not in Firefox or Safari.

Comment: how are you loading the fonts and how/when are you referencing them in your css? can you show the html structure etc

Comment: It's loaded via the link tag to googleapis in de head tag before all the CSS is loaded. Then we just use the font as font-family.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you by any chance using Django with debug_toolbar? We had the same problem with the debug toolbar. When we disabled it we didn't get the weird font styles. We're not sure why this actually happens. Think I will report this to the developers of the toolbar, maybe they can fix this.

Comment: Yes we use the debug toolbar with Django. When I disable it the problem seems to disappear! Thanks millions!